# Adding multiple values in one cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have this piece of code

```
Sub neviem()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Range
Dim j As Long

Set i = Range("GKC")

For j = i.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

    If IsEmpty(Range("E3").Value) Then
        If i(j, 1) Like Range("E2") Then
           i(j, 1).Offset(0, 1).Copy Range("E2").Offset(1, 0)
        End If

    ElseIf i(j, 1) Like Range("E2") Then
        i(j, 1).Offset(0, 1).Copy Range("E2").Offset(1, 0) & "," & Range("E2").Value
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

With this code I'm trying to add multiple text values in the same cell. The first part is ok when I run it, it will add a text value. The problem is when I run it for a second time it gives me an error

> runtime err 1004 copy method class failed

so I'm not able to put more text values next to the one I already have.

Is this possible in VBA?

Comment: The part where you have copy..... "," . This will give an error. This is no valid range to copy a value to.

Comment: Don't use `.Copy` and directly set the `.Value` of the cell. `i(j, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("E2").Offset(1, 0).Value & "," & Range("E2").Value`

Comment: @JvdV but in the first if statement it is working it is not working in the second if statement

Comment: @TooMachoBA because in the first case you are copying one range to another, while in the second you are trying to copy a string to a range.

Comment: You cannot use the Copy-Command to copy the content of more than one cell into a single. Do as @Vincent suggest, concatenate the content of the cells in VBA and write this directly to the cell - no need for Copy/Paste

Comment: Like @Vincent G says. After .copy VBA expects the range to copy to. In your first if statement this is a valid range. In your second run...well it isn't. Use .value like in Vincent his first comment.

Comment: Also, in general, whenever you can try to refrain from using copy/paste as it slows down your code significantly

Comment: @All Thank you guys for your time

Answer (score 2):

Instead this `i(j, 1).Offset(0, 1).Copy Range("E2").Offset(1, 0) & "," & Range("E2").Value`

Try this `i(j, 1).Offset(0, 1) = Range("E3") & "," & Range("E2")`